# Unity Gradle Build Failed. DexException: Multiple dex files define

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-gradle-plugin, admob

I want to make a Unity app which shows a banner ad of Admob. So, following [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start), I added the Admob Unity plugin. But, a following error occurs on building.

This is console:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -classpath "/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-4.0.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[
/Users/yuukimatsushima/work/unity/BreakPlates2/Temp/gradleOut/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35 Error:
 Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.1.0) from [:com.android.support.customtabs-26.1.0:] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35
 is also present at [:support-compat-26.0.2:] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.0.2).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:38 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processReleaseManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.1.0) from [:com.android.support.customtabs-26.1.0:] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35
   is also present at [:support-compat-26.0.2:] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.0.2).
   Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:38 to override.
...
```

Above log says `add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:38 to override.`, so I add following code.

Assets/Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        ...
        <meta-data
            tools:replace="android:value"
            android:name="android.support.VERSION"
            android:value="26.0.2" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Then an above error has resolved. However, a following error occurs.

This is console:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -classpath "/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-4.2.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformDexWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/zzd;
...
```

Please tell me how to resolve this error.
Thanks in advance.

NOTE:
Unity version: Version 2018.2.6f1 Personal

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have resolved this error by myself. In my case, the following solution worked.

1. Unity > File > Build Settings > export
2. In Android project, remove all .jar and .aar in libs except for
   unity-classes.jar and NcmbGcmPlugins.arr.
3. edit build.gradle
4. run

**This is build.gradle(app level)**

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        // EDIT: added following 3 lines.
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation(name: 'NcmbGcmPlugin', ext:'aar')
//    implementation(name: 'android.arch.lifecycle.runtime-1.0.0', ext:'aar')  // EDIT: removed
//    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.customtabs-26.1.0', ext:'aar') // EDIT: removed
//    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.support-compat-26.1.0', ext:'aar') // EDIT: removed
//    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.support-core-ui-26.1.0', ext:'aar') // EDIT: removed
//    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.support-core-utils-26.1.0', ext:'aar') // EDIT: removed
//    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.support-fragment-26.1.0', ext:'aar') // EDIT: removed
//    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0', ext:'aar') // EDIT: removed
//    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.support-v4-26.1.0', ext:'aar') // EDIT: removed
//    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-15.0.1', ext:'aar') // EDIT: removed
//    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-base-15.0.1', ext:'aar') // EDIT: removed
//    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-identifier-15.0.1', ext:'aar') // EDIT: removed
//    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-lite-15.0.1', ext:'aar') // EDIT: removed
//    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-15.0.1', ext:'aar') // EDIT: removed
//    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-gass-15.0.1', ext:'aar') // EDIT: removed
//    implementation(name: 'play-services-base-11.0.0', ext:'aar') // EDIT: removed
//    implementation(name: 'play-services-basement-11.0.0', ext:'aar') // EDIT: removed
//    implementation(name: 'play-services-gcm-11.0.0', ext:'aar') // EDIT: removed
//    implementation(name: 'play-services-iid-11.0.0', ext:'aar') // EDIT: removed
//    implementation(name: 'play-services-tasks-11.0.0', ext:'aar') // EDIT: removed
//    implementation(name: 'support-compat-26.0.2', ext:'aar') // EDIT: removed
//    implementation(name: 'support-core-utils-26.0.2', ext:'aar') // EDIT: removed
//    implementation(name: 'support-v4-26.0.2', ext:'aar') // EDIT: removed

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0' // EDIT: added
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1' // EDIT: added

    implementation project(':GoogleMobileAdsPlugin')
    implementation project(':unity-android-resources')

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        applicationId 'blue.macho.breakplates2'
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
        }
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: where is export option in build settings

Answer (score 1):

I solved the error by this:
Services -> Ads -> Advanced -> Uncheck: Enable build-in Ads extension.

credits: https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-build-multiple-dex-files-error-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-google-unity-buildconfig.542843/

Answer (score 0):

Check your external libraries in Android studio and add your build.gradle settings this code

`implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs', exclude: ['classes.jar'])
compileOnly files('libs/classes.jar')`

(classes.jar is file name include com/google/android/gms/common/api/zzd)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you mean "unity-classes.jar"? I replaced "classes.jar" for "unity-classes.jar" and add my build.gradle your code, But same error as I mentioned above has occured.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution from unity forum which works for me. Change Build System from Gradle to Internal

Reference https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-build-multiple-dex-files-error-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-google-unity-buildconfig.542843/

From sRn
"
Hey, 
I'm hoping this is Unity bug and will be resolved at some point, because I started getting this error after I updated my project to 2018.2.1f1 Unity version. 
To fix it you can try enabling Multidex, but after I did that, I got stuck on another issue, so I didn't bother anymore and returned to 2018.1.x - which works fine for me.
Also you could just change Build System from Gradle to Internal (in File->Build Settings -> Build System), which worked for me too, but I wanted to stay with Gradle to have more control, so It made more sense to get back to 2018.1.
"